# Does orientation of a USB Type-C cable matter when quick charging?

Tags: charging, htc

Is it normal that quick charging only works when plugging the (original) USB Typ-C cable in **orientation 1** into the phone and not in **orientation 2**? I mean it is symmetrical, I would have expected that both ways work. Is there a problem with my phone or is this the intended behaviour? I read [that article](https://www.howtogeek.com/211843/usb-type-c-explained-what-it-is-and-why-youll-want-it/?PageSpeed=noscript) about USB PD but it could not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB_Power_Delivery

> USB Power Delivery uses **one** of CC1, CC2 pins for power negotiation up to 20 V at 5 A (or whatever less the source can provide). It is transparent to any data transmission mode, and can therefore be used together with any of them.

Representation of USB-C Pinout:

```
GND     TX1+    TX1−    VBUS    CC1  D+ D−  SBU1    VBUS    RX2−    RX2+    GND
GND     RX1+    RX1−    VBUS    SBU2 D− D+  CC2     VBUS    TX2−    TX2+    GND
```

So I'm thinking that both the phone and the power brick that is providing power will only use one of the CC1/CC2 lines and if you twist the cable the negotiation line won't be able to connect.