# USB C symmetry problem.

Tags: usb

Up until very recently, I thought that USB C was symmetrical, that it could be plugged in either way and it always acted the same.

I now have two phones that both behave in the same manner. (HTC U11 life and Sansumg Galaxy S8) When using the factory charger and cord, connecting the plug in one orientation causes the phone to slow charge and flipping it over causes the phone to fast charge.

Was my assumption wrong to begin with or is something else the matter?

Comment: Did you try another cable?

Comment: @alex.s two cords in fact

Comment: Afaik usb-c plug pinout is not completely symmetrical. A couple of symmetrical pins have different names so they may have different functions. This maybe the reason.

Comment: My answer to a similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193997/3573

Comment: Not as per standards. Type C does away with guessing and struggling with the *right* way to connect. My guess is that your cables are not as per standard

Comment: I now think the issue is that Samsung Galaxy S8 (and perhaps the HTC U11 life) is using Qualcomm's Quick Charge protocol (or some other fast charge protocol) which is different than USB-C Power Delivery which handles the orientation issue. See: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/11/google-threatens-qualcomm-quick-charge-with-android-incompatibility/ and https://www.androidpit.com/charging-standards-comparison